# AngularJS sends nil parameters to API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, api

I created a basic API with Ruby on Rails. Whenever I try to send data from a form in AngularJS, I get this message in the Rails Server:

```
Parameters: {"{\"content\":\"message\"}"=>nil}
```

So, it's creating null records in the DB.

This is the controller in AngularJS to send the data:

```
app.controller('postController', function($scope, $http) {
  // create a blank object to handle form data.
    $scope.message = {};
  // calling submit function.
    $scope.submitForm = function() {

    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/messages',
      data    :  $scope.message, //forms user object
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
     })
      .success(function(data) { ... }
      });
    };
});
```

Comment: have you verified the contents of  `$scope.message` before you POST? What if you remove the content type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to serialize the data when you send as `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Example copied from docs

```
.controller(function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  //...

  $http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });

});
```

Or use the defaults of `$http` which sends JSON in request body as `application/json`:

```
$http.post(myurl, data).then(...;
```

Comment: (Part 1) Thank you, now is the Rails Server is throwing me a different error: _**ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.)**_

Comment: Create Method in rails is: 

**def create 
                respond_with Message.create(params[:content])
            end**

Comment: Ok, don't worry: I fixed it  with this:  **data    :  {'message': $scope.message}**

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2):

change this line:

```
headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

to:

```
headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

Also encode to Json if it isnt like this:

```
  data    :  angular.toJson($scope.message), //forms user object
```

This way you will send the correct JSON formatted data to API, make sure your API accepts Json encoded data just in case.

Comment: no need to set `'application/json'` ... that is the default and don't use `toJson` that is already done internally. Can see it already in OP's request

Comment: hey, you are right but thought it would be better to have the default written instead of what i thought wouldnt work: x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: except then OP would think it was needed every time and others who read this later with similar problems might think so also

Comment: you saw the best solution for sure, this is how I would have started to solve the problem. I just see it weird sending this content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded for json data

Comment: (Part 1) This solution worked too, but now Rails is throwing me a different message:
 _**ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.)**_

Comment: (Part 2) This is my Create method in Rails:
**def create 
                respond_with Message.create(params[:content])
            end**

Comment: Ok, don't worry: I fixed it  with this:  **data    :  {'message': $scope.message}**

And putting this in the Rails Controller: **params.require(:message).permit(:content)**

Thank you a lot.